# Birthday reset on iPhone 6

Tags: iphone, ios

I entered my birthday into my contact information on my phone very soon after I bought it, which was about a year ago. But last night (December 31st) after midnight, my phone changed my birthday to January 1st, 1989.

I've tried to change it in my contact information, but it just resets it again.

It uses this date wherever I might look at my birthday. For example, on January 1st it said happy birthday in the Notification Center. It also uses this date as my birthday in the calendar or if I ask siri

Any idea why this is happening and/or how I might be able to fix it?

Comment: is your actually birthday 1/1 of another year? or dec 31?

Comment: @Tyson My birthday is December 16th 1999

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Could you explain where precisely you are looking up your birthday on the iPhone? Are you asking siri or using the contacts app or looking on the calendar or somewhere else entirely?

Comment: @bmike Anywhere I look up my birthday it will display this date; calendar, Siri, the contacts app. In the Notification Center it says happy birthday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what was causing this. I had a Facebook account synced with my contact information, and iOS set the birthday of the contact to the birthday that was set up in Facebook. I fixed this by removing the Facebook account from my device in Settings > Facebook > [name] > Remove account

Answer (score 0):

Happy birthday Josh. My first thought is that your battery may have defaulted your system clock so you could try reboot, then make sure your clock retrieves the real time from Apple servers, make sure you set the correct timezone, then reenter your birthday on the calendar. Let us know how this turns out.